# Creating a new one-dimensional array from all positive elements of each row of a two-dimensional dynamic array in c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am a newbie programmer, so there are some problems. The program displays only 3 positive elements in a one-dimensional array, although there may be many more in a two-dimensional array.

here is my code

```
using System;

namespace task_2
{
    class arrays
    {
        public int[,] A = new int[3, 3];
        public int[] B = new int[9];
        public void two_dimensional_array()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    A[i, j] = rand.Next(-100, 100);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Two-dimensional array: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}\t", A[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        public void one_dimensional_array()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nA one-dimensional array with only positive elements: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                        if (A[i, j] > 0)
                            B[i] = A[i, j];
                }

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(B[i]);
            }
        }

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
            arrays a;
            a = new arrays();
            a.two_dimensional_array();
            a.one_dimensional_array();
        }
    }
}
```

I have attached a photo of the result below, where only three positive elements are displayed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qnjg.png)

Comment: You need to debug your code. You don't try to work out why code isn't working by looking at the end result alone. You need to look at exactly what the code does at each step. If you don't know how to debug, stop what you're doing and learn. Even if you still can't work out the solution, you should be able to tell us exactly where and how the code behaves differently from what you expect. You should be able to tell us what line it happens on, what the data was, what you expected to happen and what actually happened. Once you find that site, you can work backwards to find the cause.

Comment: Hint: consider what happens if two integers in the same row (the same value for `i` but different `j`) are positive.

Comment: You need a variable k for indexing the output : B[k++]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit this line to: (If you want `zero to be displayed instead of negative` numbers)

```
        //B[i] = A[i, j];
        B[i*3+j] = A[i, j];
```

If you want `negative numbers not to be displayed`:

```
        int index=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                    if (A[i, j] > 0)
                        B[index++] = A[i, j];
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(B[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your method `one_dimensional_array()`, you use a nested `for` loop to check all items in `A` and conditionally update items in `B`:

```csharp
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        if (A[i, j] > 0)
            B[i] = A[i, j];
    }
}
```

Using `i` and `j` to iterate over the items of `A` work as you expect: You loop through three rows and three columns.

The way you are using `i` to iterate over the indices of `B` *prevents you from iterating over all of `B`'s indices*. You are actually only looping over index 0, 1 and 2 (as per your instructions of `i`'s possible range in the outer `for` loop).

In your nested loop, you will hit the `if (A[i, j] > 0)` line nine times. The values of `i`, `j`, `A[i, j]` and `B[i]` will change as follows:

```
|  i  |  j  |  A[i, j]  |  B[i]  |
|-----|-----|-----------|--------|
|  0  |  0  |  A[0, 0]  |  B[0]  |
|  0  |  1  |  A[0, 1]  |  B[0]  |
|  0  |  2  |  A[0, 2]  |  B[0]  |
|-----|-----|-----------|--------|
|  1  |  0  |  A[1, 0]  |  B[1]  |
|  1  |  1  |  A[1, 1]  |  B[1]  |
|  1  |  2  |  A[1, 2]  |  B[1]  |
|-----|-----|-----------|--------|
|  2  |  0  |  A[2, 0]  |  B[2]  |
|  2  |  1  |  A[2, 1]  |  B[2]  |
|  2  |  2  |  A[2, 2]  |  B[2]  |
```

As a result,

- **`B[0]`** is assigned the ***last* positive value in the *first* row in `A`** (if any value in that row is positive)
- **`B[1]`** is assigned the ***last* positive value in the *second* row in `A`** (if any value in that row is positive)
- **`B[2]`** is assigned the ***last* positive value in the *third* row in `A`** (if any value in that row is positive)

So, you need a way to iterate over all of `B`'s indices (i.e. `0`--`8`).

It is possible to calculate such a parameter based on the already existing `i` and `j` values:

> var k = f(i, j)

which can be used as follows:

```
B[k] = A[i, j];
```

Can you figure out the expression for `k`?